# Best algorithm to discriminate between text blocks containing words and text blocks containing gibberish

Tags: java

What is the best way to discriminate between strings of text that contain proper sentences i.e

```
The cat sat on the hat
```

And strings that contain pure gibberish

```
$ $ #@^^sSss .....$$ 2 dzw6^^^#73@2 ## @=^^
```

in java.

Comment: You could use the The Stanford Parser.

Comment: Or a dictionary and just see what percentage of the words match, perhaps with some auto-spell check.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a proper parser resp. dictionary for the language or you don't know the language beforehand, some assumptions might help you, e.g.:

- proper text is made of words, which are made of letters, with blanks between words and a few punctuation marks and maybe numbers
- words have typical range for their length, even in languages that allow for arbitrarily long words (e.g. German)
- typically, a word is either all lowercase, initial uppercase or all uppercase

Write a function that tests the string for those assumptions, run several tests on existing texts, to define boundaries to what extent a string must conform to these rules to be acceptable as "proper text".